# What is the terminal for apple screen time?

Tags: terminal.app

Quick question. What is the terminal term for  Screen Time? I have tried to find it using 'help', but it will not show me any commands related to screen time.

Comment: I would love to be able to script approvals... It's such a pain when they pop up. I wonder if shortcuts will ever include them.

Answer (score 3):

There's a daemon called `ScreenTimeAgent`, but it's buried deep in the ScreenTimeCore framework directory and clearly not intended to be used as a command-line interface to the Screen Time feature.

I don't believe there is any command-line tool for accessing the Screen Time feature. Screen Time is exclusively configured though the Screen Time panel in System Preferences.